# LinearLayout overlapping Support CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

It's the first time I use CoordinatorLayout, and I don't really understand how it works.

My LinearLayout is overlapping my Toolbar, as if I were in a FrameLayout, or RelativeLayout, and I don't know how to tell it to go below ( Like android:layout_below with RelativeLayout )

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo2"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            .... Very Large Form ...
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Another doubt: Almost all the examples I saw were with CoordinateLayout managing RecyclerView. 
My Layout is not a RecyclerView, just a very long form. Does it make sense doing it this way?

Comment: </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout> closing tag is broken as there is no opening one

Comment: upps my mistake pasting code ! Fixed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try nesting your content inside of a NestedScrollView. Don't forget to include the layout_behavior XML tag.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     <!-- Your scrolling content -->

 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Additional resources:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Comment: because if you forget do the almighty `layout_behavior` you are going to have a tough time figuring out why does your actionbar go under the scroll view no matter what. I am happy I have found this solution, even happier that now `Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner` is behind me (do not dare to pass a semi opaque colour to its background). Now I should get back to figuring why most of my text views will pick up the theme/specific textColor attribute while two of them won't. Gee... I really miss the good Android days when there was no material and support madness

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. I suppose it's not be the best solution out there, but it makes everything looks OK and it allow us to continue with CoordinatorLayout's animations.

I just set the Fragment's margintTop and marginBot to the exact same DPs that the toolbar on top has and that the bottom nav bar has.

In my case, my toolbar and my navbar have "?attr/actionBarSize" height. So I just set the top and bot margins of my fragment to "?attr/actionBarSize"

Again, it's not as good as using Linear or Relative Layout, but I'm afraid if we chose that solution we waste CoordinatorLayout's animations.

on Toolbar and BottomNavBar:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

and in my Fragment:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: the only bad thing with this is if you hide your appbar then the space where it 'was' will not be filled. Have a look at insetEdge and dodgeInsetEdge

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but it might still help someone.

Enclose all the chidren of `CoordinatorLayout` into a `LinearLayout`, *vertical orientation*.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make your appbar have an [insetEdge](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams#insetEdge) of TOP and your content layout a [dodgeInset](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams#dodgeInsetEdges) of ALL or TOP. This will make your linearlayout not overlap with the appbar.

Answer (score -2):

From developer.android.com

*"CoordinatorLayout is a super-powered FrameLayout.
CoordinatorLayout is intended for two primary use cases:
As a top-level application decor or chrome layout
As a container for a specific interaction with one or more child views
By specifying Behaviors for child views of a CoordinatorLayout you can provide many different interactions within a single parent and those views can also interact with one another. View classes can specify a default behavior when used as a child of a CoordinatorLayout using the DefaultBehavior annotation.
Behaviors may be used to implement a variety of interactions and additional layout modifications ranging from sliding drawers and panels to swipe-dismissable elements and buttons that stick to other elements as they move and animate.
Children of a CoordinatorLayout may have an anchor. This view id must correspond to an arbitrary descendant of the CoordinatorLayout, but it may not be the anchored child itself or a descendant of the anchored child. This can be used to place floating views relative to other arbitrary content panes."*

So, you can change the root view to LinearLayout(vertical orientation) or use scrollview, which would arrange the children linearly.

Comment: This is not a real answer, you may quote this, but you are not helping him and the community at all.