# Android ScrollView is not scrolling the content

Tags: android, android-layout

I have read dozens of similar posts here on StackExchange, however none of the suggestions have worked for me so far.  This behavior is consistent in both the emulator and on my device (emulator is Nexus 5, device is Nexus 5X).

I've got several factors that could be contributing to the complexity. First, I am using fragments.  Second, I am using a TableLayout inside the ScrollView.  I am adding table rows programatically; each row contains two text views, thus creating two columns.

Here is my main activity layout XML (when loading the fragments, they are placed into fragment_container):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.searches.saved.ViewSearchesActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my fragment layout XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context="com.jpvander.githubjobs.activities.searches.saved.ViewJobDetailsFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/table_layout"></TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the fragment code:

```
package com.jpvander.githubjobs.activities.searches.saved;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.jpvander.githubjobs.R;
import com.jpvander.githubjobs.datasets.GitHubJob;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class ViewJobDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final float PADDING_DP = 10.0f;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private GitHubJob jobSelected;

    public ViewJobDetailsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View jobDetailsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_job_details, container, false);
        TableLayout jobDetailsTable = (TableLayout) jobDetailsView.findViewById(R.id.table_layout);

        if (null == jobSelected) {
            jobSelected = new GitHubJob();
            jobSelected.setTitle("Product Tester");
            jobSelected.setCompany("ACME");
            jobSelected.setLocation("Monument Valley, UT");
            jobSelected.setDescription("Looking for a bright but accident-prone coyote for product testing");
        }

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> rowData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        rowData.put("Company:", jobSelected.getCompany());
        rowData.put("Location:", jobSelected.getLocation());
        rowData.put("Title:", jobSelected.getTitle());
        rowData.put("Description:", jobSelected.getDescription());

        TableRow tableRow;
        TextView label;
        TextView content;
        float displayScale = this.getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int paddingPx = (int) (PADDING_DP * displayScale + 0.5f);

        for (String key : rowData.keySet()) {
            tableRow = new TableRow(this.getActivity());
            tableRow.setPadding(0, paddingPx, paddingPx, paddingPx);
            label = new TextView(this.getActivity());
            label.setPadding(0, 0, paddingPx, 0);
            label.setText(key);
            content = new TextView(this.getActivity());
            content.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            content.setText(rowData.get(key));
            tableRow.addView(label);
            tableRow.addView(content);
            jobDetailsTable.addView(tableRow);
        }

        return jobDetailsView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public void setJobSelected(GitHubJob job) {
        this.jobSelected = job;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onViewJobDetailsInteraction(GitHubJob job);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, if You want to have list with items (containing 2 views) why don't you use recyclerView and viewHolder? Does your question require to have table layout under toolbar?

Comment: Have you tried using NestedScrollView?

Comment: Yes give the `NestedScrollView` a try but you'll also need to set the `app:layout_behavior` on it or your `ScrollView` - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940698/linearlayout-overlapping-support-coordinatorlayout

Comment: Actually looking at the layout you could set the `app:layout_behavior` on your `FrameLayout`. You also probably don't want to nest the `FrameLayout` in the `AppBarLayout`

Comment: Hi Cory - it is necessary to put the FrameLayout in the AppBarLayout, otherwise the top part of it is obscured by the toolbar.  Deadfish, does the RecyclerView have built-in scrolling?  That is a question I also had, and if I interpret your response correctly, that is the implication.  My concern with using RecyclerView is that I need the two columns one-to-one, side-by-side, with the columns aligned, and I am not sure how to do that with RecyclerView. Charlton and Alex, I will give NestedScrollView a try and let everyone know how it goes. Thank you all for taking the time to reply!

Comment: Well it turns out Cory was closest to the mark.  The AppBarLayout swallows the swipes.  However, when I put the FrameLayout outside of it, as I mentioned, part of that view is "underneath" the toolbar that is in the AppBarLayout.  I wrapped the AppBarLayout and FrameLayout in a vertical LinearLayout, and I got all the things I wanted.  I had to do that manually in the XML text, because Android Studio wouldn't let me put the LinearLayout in via the Design tab :(  Android Studio auto-created the layout with this unfortunate trap in it, but at least I've learned quite a bit from the struggle :)